Build input file cannot be found and xcode is searching file at wrong path after pod install
i am getting this error after pod install in xcode
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'abcQA' from project 'abc') this file ibstdc++.6.0.9.dylib is present at 
'/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib'
but dont know after pod install commnads it changing to
'/usr/lib and searching there but in file path and all project setting path is /usr/local/lib/


OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -weak_library /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib it changes liek this before pod install it was /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib

Also if I add the path manually /usr/local/lib/
inside pods file then i am able run the build successfully
Post-install script:
      config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['/usr/local/lib']

